# Unsafe member access .body on an any value error with eslint-typescript and Express

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, eslint

I get an error from this rule, `@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access` when I try to access the request body in my API. My project contains JavaScript and TypeScript code and uses Express.

**server.js:**

```
server.post('url', apiFunction);
```

**app.ts:**

```
export function apiFunction(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
   const requestVariable: number = req.body.requestVariable;
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
"env": {
    "es6":true,
    "node":true,
"jest":true
},
"extends": [
"eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking'
    ],
"parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": 2017,
    'project': './tsconfig.eslint.json'
}
,
"globals": {
  "Rx": true
},
"rules": {
  "@typescript-eslint/indent": [
      2,
      2
        ],
  "linebreak-style": [
      2,
      "unix"
  ],
  "quotes": [
      2,
      "single"
  ],
  "semi": [
      2,
      "always"
  ],
  "no-console":[
    0
  ]
}
```

eslint keeps saying that I cannot access `req.body.request` because `req` is typed `any`. The exact is error is this: `Unsafe member access .body on any value`.

However, my code works correctly. My project has both JavaScript and TypeScript code at the moment. So, the server is written in JavaScript and the function is written in TypeScript. Is that why the `req` parameter has an `any` type instead of a `Request` type?

Comment: Have you installed `@types/express`?

Comment: yes I have. I ran npm install @types/express again just in case

Comment: I also get the error "Unsafe assignment of an any value" at the same line

Comment: Have you imported those types?

Comment: Yes this is my import statement: import { Request, Response } from 'express';

Comment: Should work in that case. Might be something to do with your TS/eslint config

Comment: I added my eslint config if you want to take a look

Comment: I wouldn't know just from looking. I'd suggest removing different rules to see if any of them cause it

Comment: When I remove the plugin, 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking', it works but I don't think it is checking if all the variables have data types defined then.

Comment: Now I get this error, Unsafe member access .requestVariable on an any value instead of .body. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Is there a rule in eslint that makes sure all variables have a datatype assigned to them. So, 'const a = 1' shouldn't be allowed